# Bash Script for mounting share and starting rsync

Tags: macos, mount, rsync

There is a need to migrate data from one server to another as we begin decommissioning the first server; the first server is an OS X 10.9.5 machine. I would like to devise a script that, when launched, would auto-mount the appropriate share points and begin rsyncing the data over. Here's what I have, except it's not working

```
echo "Mounting Share..."
mkdir /tmp/Share
mount_smbfs //$USER:$PASSWORD@server.domain.com/Share /tmp/Share
rsync -vuhma --progress /Volumes/Path/SharedFolders/Share/ /tmp/DocShare
```

The script makes it's way to this point and all hell breaks loose. It makes the directory, starts the mount process but doesn't wait for the mount to actually take place before it starts rsync. This causes rsync to just dump files into a folder, not the actual share point.

How can I make sure that the script pauses while mounting the volume before starting rsync?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add this to your script which checks the device ID of the root filesystem against the mountpoint /tmp/Share. The script exits after 10 tries.

```
count=0
while :
do if  [ "$(stat -f %d /)" -ne "$(stat -f %d /tmp/Share)" ]
   then rsync …… #put the full command here (watch your paths)
   else if [ "$count" -lt 10 ]
        then echo "Waiting for the filesystem to mount"
             ((count++))
             sleep 1
        else echo "CANNOT MOUNT THE FILESYSTEM"
             exit
        fi
  fi
done
```